# how to access a controller return value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I've a java script function that is used to save a webcam Image and the code is as below.

```
onCapture: function () {
                webcam.save("@Url.Content("~/Image/ImageCapture")/");
                MatchFindFunction();
            }
```

and in my controller the code is as below.

```
public void ImageCapture() //Capturing the image and save to folder
        {

            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(@"~/Temp")))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"~/Temp"));
            }

            string sessionIdValue = getSessionID();
            tempPath = "~/Temp/" + sessionIdValue + ".jpg";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["tempImagePath"] = sessionIdValue;

            CommonModel.path = Server.MapPath(tempPath);
            CommonModel.stream = Request.InputStream;
            using (CommonModel.reader = new StreamReader(CommonModel.stream))
                CommonModel.dump = CommonModel.reader.ReadToEnd();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(CommonModel.path, ConvertStringToByte(CommonModel.dump));
return sessionIdValue;
        }
```

So Here my requirements is, I want to get this returned value in Javascript, I have to pass this variable to another function. I tried doing `alert(webcam.save("@Url.Content("~/Image/ImageCapture")/"))`, but the message alerted here is `true`, but I want the sessionIdValue in return. I'm confused, if I have to use Ajax, if so, I'm not sure of how to call this URL. As this is webcam save method.

Please let me know on how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `@Url.Content("~/Image/ImageCapture")` is your return value. just use this instead of using `webcam.save("@Url.Content("~/Image/ImageCapture")/"` in `alert` function.

Comment: and if you can't access this value as an image or string, then must check the action.

Comment: Hi @Eisa, Thanks for the quick response, Unfortunately, the response that I get is `/Image/ImageCapture`. :( please let me know where am I going wrong...

Comment: first of all check what is response value when you call this action.
type `[local host or IP]/Image/ImageCapture` in address bar..

Comment: If response is an image, then use `$([selector of an image]).attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/Image/ImageCapture")');` to show it in an image tag.

Comment: Hi @Eisa, apologies for the delayed response, when I did `[local host or IP]/Image/ImageCapture`, I'm getting a string in my webpage, and this is exactly that I need. Can you please let me know how can I do this

Comment: @user3872094 Ok good, well it is the address of your content,  what do you wanna do with this string?

Comment: I want to alert this value in Javascript alert, just above my `Matchfindfunction()`

Comment: Try `alert("[local host or IP]/Image/ImageCapture");`

Comment: That's a quite good suggestion, but my problem is, I'm going to deploy this onto Azure, there I don't think this would be recommended solution :-(

Comment: Do you mean resolving URL? check [this](https://webactivedirectory.com/asp-net/asp-net-use-url-content-from-razor-to-resolve-relative-urls/) for resolving URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136372/discussion-between-eisa-and-user3872094).

Comment: @user3872094 Do you get what you wanted?